# How to set HDMI output exclusively to audio and prevent it from recognizing it as a display?

Tags: sound, 20.04, hdmi, display-manager

I have connected my Ubuntu 20.4 desktop computer with my av-receiver to get audio output via HDMI to my sound system. This is working, but it has the side effect, that my av-receiver is also recognized as a display device. Thus, in Settings → Displays I now have a third monitor. This is not ideal, because my mouse sometimes disappears into that area.

When I disable the display, then not only the video but also the audio is gone. So how do I treat my Yamaha av-receiver as an audio device only?

Comment: Have you tried defining the Yamaha Monitor as mirrored to another monitor? Then when the mouse moves into the Yamaha Monitor it is actually moving into a real monitor.

Comment: The audio is embedded into the video in hdmi: https://hardforum.com/threads/is-there-a-way-to-output-sound-by-hdmi-without-video.1896250/

Comment: Thank you! That link describes the same issues, but the answers are less than ideal :(

Comment: The answers there seem to confirm setting up the Yamaha monitor as a mirrored image of your existing monitor. Have you tried setting up the Yamaha monitor as a mirror to existing monitor? Note please use `@personsname` for them to get your comment directly.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I did look for that option but i did not find it in Settings -> Displays. I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457616/mirror-displays-with-ubuntu-14-04#457625) but i don't have that check box. Do you have a suggestion how to do it please?

Comment: You found an answer for Ubuntu 14.04 not Ubuntu 20.04 which you are using. Also your answer has German screenshots rather than English... Try this more current answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096306/no-option-to-mirror-displays-on-18-04-dell-m3800